# Site installation fails with "No database to operate on."

Tags: drush

I am having some problems running drush site install through Puppet.  When it comes for puppet to execute the following command I get an error.  It appears as though the database URL is being truncated and then some non-verbose error tells me SQL cannot execute?  If I try to install the site via the web-UI it works without any issues. I can connect from this machine using the MySQL client with username/password.

The output of `/usr/bin/php /var/webdeploy/src/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php site-install -y -r /var/www/html/drupal --db-url=data.rds.awsdomain.com/dbname --db-su=user --db-su-pw=password    --account-name=admin --account-pass=admin --account-mail=mail@example.com --site-name="site name" minimal` is the following.

> You are about to CREATE  the 'ata.rds.awsdomain.com/dbname' database. Do you want to continue? (y/n): y
> Unable to generate CREATE DATABASE sql for
> No database to operate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your --db-url is not in the correct format.  Use this instead:

`--db-url=mysql://USER@data.rds.awsdomain.com/dbname`

Replace USER with the account used to access the database.  If this is the same user that you have specified with --db-su, then the --db-su option is not necessary.  Drush will not go the other way (fill in the "ordinary" user from the privileged user specified via --db-su), though.